# Живут или живёт — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, сказуемые, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно?

> Здесь жив**у**т (жив**ё**т) Иван и дети.
> Здесь жив**у**т (жив**ё**т) Мазай и зайцы.

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что правильней использовать форму множественного числа сказуемого:
Здесь живут Иван и дети.
Здесь живут Мазай и зайцы.

*Дети, зайцы* — одушевленные существительные во множественном числе.

На согласование сказуемого оказывает влияние множественное число одного из однородных подлежащих:
*В постель её уложили ревность и слёзы* (Чехов).
Кроме того, форма множественного числа предпочтительнее, если подчёркивается большое число действующих лиц (обычно это одушевлённые субъекты):
*Кричали Витя, Павлик, Кирилл и бегавший кругом них Арсений Романович.*

Две односпальные койки в доме означали, что здесь живут только Лиза и её мать и у Лизы нет ни мужа, ни отца. [Алексей Иванов (Алексей Маврин). Псоглавцы. Гл. 1-20 (2011)]

Здесь живут губернатор, депутаты, крупные предприниматели ― домашний союз чиновничества и купечества. [Юлия Вишневецкая. Почему Россия — не Москва // «Русский репортер», № 43 (122), 12-19 ноября 2009]

[§ 190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliii-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-podlezhashchim/ss-190-soglasovanie-skazuemogo-s-odnorodnymi-podlezhashchimi)
[Некоторые особенности согласования](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html)

Comment: _Римма Михайлова: "Я думаю, что правильной..."_ === По-моему, вместо "правильной" лучше написать "правильней".

Comment: М-м... Прямо-таки озадачили, Слава. Рассуждаю так: форма множественного числа сказуемого будет (какой?) правильной. Из двух предполагаемых — одна будет правильной. Или есть какой-то другой смысл?

Comment: Да я и сам выбрал бы форму множ. числа. И проголосовал за Ваш ответ. Но утверждать, что только эта форма единственно правильна в разбираемых примерах, не могу. Потому и предложил это "правильней" (= правильнее)… Ср.: _Он считает своим "домом родным" — свою деревню, где **живёт** он и его близкие._ Обязательна ли здесь форма множ. числа? Или "живёт" — тоже правильно?

Comment: Спасибо за плюсик и внимание к моему ответу. Я нашла указанное Вами предложение. Знаете, несмотря на то, что оно из учебника (то есть теоретически должно быть проверенным со всех сторон), я бы и в нем выбрала множественное число — живут он и его близкие.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Строгого ограничения тут нет, можно использовать любую форму.

По смыслу, множественное число разделяет деятельность на все подлежащие поровну, а единственное выделяет некоего лидера из перечисления (первое однородное подлежащее).

Есть еще конвенция, согласно которой, если сказуемое предшествует подлежащим, то используется форма единственного числа, а если идет после, то множественного:

`живет Мазай и заяц`

`Мазай и заяц живут`

Но ей часто пренебрегают и официальным правилом она не является.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что предпочтительно во множественном, но и в единственном не ошибка если хочу подчеркнуть некоего лидера из перечисления?